# How can I update expiration of a document in Couchbase using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, couchbase, sql++

We have a lot of docs in Couchbase with expiration = 0, which means that documents stay in Couchbase forever. I am aware that INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE isn't supported by N1QL.

We have 500,000,000 such docs and I would like to do this in parallel using chunks/bulks. How can I update the expiration field using Python 3?

I am trying this:

```
bucket.touch_multi(('000c4894abc23031eed1e8dda9e3b120', '000f311ea801638b5aba8c8405faea47'), ttl=10)
```

However I am getting an error like:

```
_NotFoundError_0xD (generated, catch NotFoundError): <Key=u'000c4894abc23031eed1e8dda9e3b120'
```

Comment: Allow me to suggest you to kindly provide examples of what you have tried so far. A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelFayad I am trying to do this with `bucket.touch_multi(('000c4894abc23031eed1e8dda9e3b120', '000f311ea801638b5aba8c8405faea47'), ttl=10)` But getting an error like: _NotFoundError_0xD (generated, catch NotFoundError): <Key=u'000c4894abc23031eed1e8dda9e3b120'

Comment: Same with lists of id's provided to the touch_multi function

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this:

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator
cluster = Cluster('couchbase://localhost')
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('Administrator', 'password')
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
cb = cluster.open_bucket('default')

keys = []
for i in range(10):
    keys.append("key_{}".format(i))

for key in keys:
    cb.upsert(key, {"some":"thing"})

print(cb.touch_multi(keys, ttl=5))
```

and I get no errors, just a dictionary of keys and OperationResults.  And they do in fact expire soon thereafter.  I'd guess some of your keys are not there.

However maybe you'd really rather set a bucket expiry?  That will make *all* the documents expire in that time, regardless of what the expiry on the individual documents are. In addition to the above answer that mentions that, check out [this](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/understanding-couchbase/buckets-memory-and-storage/expiration.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Couchbase Python (Any) SDK Bucket.touch() method Described here https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/document-operations.html#modifying-expiraton

If you don't know the document keys you can use N1QL Covered index get the document keys asynchronously inside your python SDK and use the above  bucket touch API set expiration from your python SDK.

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON  bucket(META().id) WHERE META().expiration = 0;
SELECT RAW META().id 
FROM bucket WHERE META().expiration = 0 AND META().id LIKE "a%";
```

You can issue different SELECT's for different ranges and do in parallel.

Update Operation, You need to write one. As you get each key do (instead of update)  bucket.touch(), which only updates document expiration without modifying the actual document. That saves get/put of whole document (https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/core-operations.html#setting-document-expiration).

Comment: I am trying to do this with `bucket.touch_multi(('000c4894abc23031eed1e8dda9e3b120', '000f311ea801638b5aba8c8405faea47'), ttl=10)`

But getting an error like:
_NotFoundError_0xD (generated, catch NotFoundError): <Key=u'000c4894abc23031eed1e8dda9e3b120' @vsr

Comment: make sure key exist and not expired.